# How to filter a question from Watson assistant intent?

Tags: android-intent, response, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have multiple questions under the same intent in Watson assistant. How to get reply to specific question rather than checking whole intent?

Comment: Can you add some examples of your questions in the intent?

Comment: Yes sure.I created an intent as #greeting and question are Good Morning,Good Afternoon,Good Night etc.if user typed Good morning or any thing above mentioned question ten i want to show response Good Morning Have a nice day etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many concepts/features of Watson Assistant using which you can achieve this. Once such feature is [Context Variables](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant/dialog-runtime.html#context-variables). You can create an intent called `day` and add good morning, afternoon and evening as examples or add them as examples to your `greeting` intent. The more the examples the better and add the intent to the Dialog as a node.

Then you can edit the context in the editor and create a context variable called `user_input` which will take user input like good morning and pass that as a response from the bot. You can find that in the image below. You can use the context variable in any node of the Dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The best way to do this case is enabling Multiple responses

[image]

if you use`<? input.text ?>` to print greeting maybe you face some issue like if the user says "Hey Bot Good Morning" then, in that case, input.text print as it is